# "Stopped me wearing shoes" vs "stopped me FROM wearing shoes"

Tags: verbs, prepositions

The article below has a title *"These ultra-tough socks almost stopped me wearing shoes"*

Should it be *"These ultra-tough socks almost stopped me **FROM** wearing shoes"*?

I've been seeing "from" omitted a lot lately before the verb and it sounds incorrect.

http://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/7/20/12234710/skinners-socks-shoes-review-hands-on

Comment: Although it strictly doesnt' adhere to the fundamental grammar, these ommited usages of prepositions is common

Comment: You are correct; however, much has been written here about "headlinese," of which this may or may not be an example. Do a search on headlinese for more information if you are interested. Certainly, at least to my ear, "These ultra-tough socks almost stopped me wearing shoes" sounds ridiculous.

Comment: I'd love to know where it does sound correct, and who started this.

Comment: I would guess it's a corruption of 'my'. 'Stopped my wearing shoes' is grammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the socks *started* you wearing shoes, would you have any question about where the preposition went?

I think that the reason that "from" is not usually dropped is mental association with "keep".

"To keep you doing something" means the opposite of "to keep you from doing something", the preposition is vital, and I think that has carried over to other verbs.  Negative words like "discourage", "forbid", and "distract" can take "from"; "start", "recommend", and "advise" need no preposition.